# Intercomponent Communication Angular 6

Tags: angular6

I have an Angular 6 application with one page where list of all records are shown from database in a table.
This feature is handled by a separate angular component as below :

```
export class ReceiveOrderComponent implements OnInit{
//not entire code is shown 

 constructor(private _orderService : OrderService,
              private _downloadService : DownloadService) { }

//method to receive all orders by using OrderService

}
```

There is a download button in this **SAME** component template ( `receive.component.html` )which when clicked triggers a download of a file of the selected record.

Actual download (`http communication` ) is handled by `DownloadService` 
and this service is injected into `ReceiveOrderComponent` as shown above.

But I want to keep download functionality in a separate component `(DownloadComponent)` and have  `DownloadService` injected into that component loke below  :

```
export class DownloadComponent implements OnInit{
//not entire code is shown 

 constructor(private _downloadService : DownloadService) { }

}
```

The issue is `receive.component.html` is in `ReceiveOrderComponent` and the click action should invoke a method in **ANOTHER COMPONENT** (i.e `DownloadComponent`)
and not in `ReceiveOrderComponent` whom  `receive.component.html` belongs to

Can you please let me know how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Atul you can as Input ,Output Emitter (*Broadcasting ) to communication as defrent component 
IE:-

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-child',
  template: `
    <h3>{{hero.name}} says:</h3>
    <p>I, {{hero.name}}, am at your service, {{masterName}}.</p>
  `
})
export class HeroChildComponent {
  @Input() hero: Hero;
  @Input('master') masterName: string;
}

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { HEROES } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-parent',
  template: `
    <h2>{{master}} controls {{heroes.length}} heroes</h2>
    <app-hero-child *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
      [hero]="hero"
      [master]="master">
    </app-hero-child>
  `
})
export class HeroParentComponent {`enter code here`
  heroes = HEROES;
  master = 'Master';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

const subject = new Subject();

subject.next('missed message from Subject');

subject.subscribe(v => console.log(v));

subject.next('hello from subject!');
```